# Linking c++ library with CMake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, activemq-classic

I'm tring to use CMS and cannot link libraries that i compiled on my linux. My CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(region_algorithm)
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
    /usr/local/include/activemq-cpp-3.8.3
    /usr/local/apr/include/apr-1)
link_libraries(
    /usr/local/lib/libactivemq-cpp.a
    /usr/local/apr/lib/libapr-1.a)
```

When i'm building project i got errors like:

```
regionalgorithmconsumer.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to 
  `decaf::util::concurrent::CountDownLatch::CountDownLatch(int)'
```

Comment: Can you use `nm` or `objdump` and grep for `decaf` to see if it's in either of those libraries you've linked?  Also, do yourself a favor and don't use the magic `aux_source_directory()`--it's better practice in CMake to explicit list the source files you need, to avoid surprises and broken dependency analysis.

Comment: Ummm what version of cmake are you using? `link_libraries` is deprecated. It will add the specified libs to all targets declared later on. Why won't you use, `find_package` and `target_link_libraries`?

Comment: can you show any example of using that? I'm new with cmake. About library. When i compiled activemq i had also decaf and cms headers but no *.a files. I assumed that activemq*.a contains decaf and cms also. Is it wrong assumption?